# Installing of SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have the last version of R - 3.2.1. Now I want to install SparkR on R. After I execute:

```
> install.packages("SparkR")
```

I got back:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘SparkR’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

I have also installed Spark on my machine

```
Spark 1.4.0
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601252/why-sparkr-isnt-available-in-cran-r-package-list

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can install directly from a GitHub repository:

```
if (!require('devtools')) install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('apache/spark@v2.x.x', subdir='R/pkg')
```

You should choose tag (`v2.x.x` above) corresponding to the version of Spark you use. You can find a full list of tags on the [project page](https://github.com/apache/spark) or directly from R using [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags):

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/apache/spark/tags")$name
```

If you've downloaded binary package from [a downloads page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) R library is in a `R/lib/SparkR` subdirectory. It can be used to install `SparkR` directly. For example:

```
$ export SPARK_HOME=/path/to/spark/directory
$ cd $SPARK_HOME/R/pkg/
$ R -e "devtools::install('.')"
```

You can also add R lib to `.libPaths` (taken from [here](http://sgsong.blogspot.co.il/2015/06/how-to-use-sparkr-within-rstudio.html)):

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='/path/to/spark/directory')
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'), .libPaths()))
```

Finally, you can use `sparkR` shell without any additional steps:

```
$ /path/to/spark/directory/bin/sparkR
```

**Edit**

According to [Spark 2.1.0 Release Notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-1-0.html) should be available on CRAN in the future:

> Standalone installable package built with the Apache Spark release. We will be submitting this to CRAN soon.

You can follow [SPARK-15799](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15799) to check the progress.

**Edit 2**

While SPARK-15799 has been merged, satisfying CRAN requirements proved to be challenging (see for example discussions about [2.2.2](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Fwd-CRAN-pretest-archived-CRAN-submission-SparkR-2-2-2-td24388.html), [2.3.1](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Fwd-CRAN-pretest-archived-CRAN-submission-SparkR-2-3-1-td24171.html), [2.4.0](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Fwd-CRAN-pretest-archived-CRAN-submission-SparkR-2-4-0-td25621.html#a25674)), and the packages has been subsequently removed (see for example [SparkR was removed from CRAN on 2018-05-01](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/SparkR-was-removed-from-CRAN-on-2018-05-01-td24035.html), [CRAN SparkR package removed?](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/SparkR-was-removed-from-CRAN-on-2018-05-01-td24035.html)). As the result methods listed in the original post are still the most reliable solutions.

**Edit 3**

OK, [`SparkR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparkR/index.html) is back up on CRAN again, v2.4.1. `install.packages('SparkR')` should work again (it may take a couple of days for the mirrors to reflect this)

Comment: Also note that the above does _not_ install the documentation. As near as I can tell, you'll need to clone the repo and [follow the instructions here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/DOCUMENTATION.md)

Comment: `SparkR` is not in CRAN again.

Answer (score 10):

SparkR requires not just an R package but an entire Spark backend to be pulled in. When you want to upgrade SparkR, you are upgrading Spark, not just the R package. If you want to go with SparkR then this blogpost might help you out: https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/07/14/spark-1-4-for-rstudio/.

It should be said though: nowadays you may want to refer to the sparklyr package as it makes all of this a whole lot easier.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "1.6.2")
spark_install(version = "2.0.0")
```

It also offers more functionality than SparkR as well as a very nice interface to `dplyr`.

Comment: thank you for the info sharing about upgrade startegy!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will too update to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced similar issue while trying to play with SparkR in EMR with Spark 2.0.0. I'll post the steps here that I followed to install rstudio server, SparkR, sparklyr, and finally connecting to a spark session in a EMR cluster:

1. Install rstudio server:
   After the EMR cluster is up and running, ssh to the master node with user 'hadoop@' and download rstudio server

> wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.903-x86_64.rpm

then install using `yum install`

> sudo yum install --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.903-x86_64.rpm

finally add a user to access rstudio web console as:

> sudo su
>
> sudo useradd username
>
> sudo echo username:password | chpasswd

2. To acess rstudio Web console you need to create a SSH tunnel from your machine to the EMR master node like below:

> ssh -NL 8787:ec2-emr-master-node-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8787 hadoop@ec2-emr-master-node-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com&

3. Now open any browser and type `localhost:8787` to go the rstudio Web console and use the `username:password` combo to login.
4. To install the required R packages you need to install `libcurl` into the master node first like below:

> sudo yum update
>
> sudo yum -y install libcurl-devel

5. Resolve permission issues with:

> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/
>
> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown  /user/

6. Check Spark version in EMR and set `SPARK_HOME`:

> spark-submit --version
>
> export SPARK_HOME='/usr/lib/spark/'

6. Now in the rstudio console install `SparkR` like below:

> install.packages('devtools')
>
> devtools::install_github('apache/spark@v2.0.0', subdir='R/pkg')
>
> install.packages('sparklyr')
>
> library(SparkR)
>
> library(sparklyr)
>
> Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='/usr/lib/spark')
>
> sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client")

Answer (score 2):

Now versions 2.1.2 and 2.3.0 of SparkR are now available in the repository of [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SparkR/), you can install version 2.3.0 as follows:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SparkR/SparkR_2.3.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

**Note:** You must first download and install the corresponding version of Apache Spark from [download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), so that the package works correctly.