# why SparkR isn't available in CRAN R package list?

Tags: r, apache-spark, package, sparkr

I checked for sparkR package in CRAN package list through the following link.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html

This list does not include sparkR, and therefore installing sparkR through `install.packages("package_name")` cannot be done.

Why isn't sparkR listed in the package list?

Comment: [`SparkR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparkR/index.html) is in fact on CRAN

Comment: @MichaelChirico [Not anymore](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparkR/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 1.4, SparkR is not a separate package anymore but has been integrated with Apache Spark. So I guess it doesn't make sense anymore to create a CRAN R package for it.

Comment: [`SparkR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparkR/index.html) is on CRAN