# Error while Installing sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sbt, sparkr

I'm trying to install SparkR

```
library(devtools)
install_github("amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg", subdir="pkg")
```

but then I find this error

> Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.6.jar
>   Invalid or corrupt jarfile sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.6.jar
>   make: *** [target/scala-2.10/sparkr-assembly-0.1.jar] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘SparkR’
>   * removing ‘/Users/apple/Library/R/3.2/library/SparkR’
>   Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: this post was given and mentioned that the problem is with "Make" , may help you solve it https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205133157-ERROR-compilation-failed-for-package-SparkR-

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: because running big data with R is a pain of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read before proceeding**:

amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg is no longer maintained. Current versions of SparkR are shipped with Spark itself. See also [Installing of SparkR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31184918/1560062)

---

Sbt download links in the repository are invalid and what you get is actually a HTML file. You can either correct `URL2` in [`pkg/src/sbt/sbt`](https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg/blob/master/pkg/src/sbt/sbt) so it points to:

```
http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.6/sbt-launch.jar
```

or [download and install sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Manual-Installation.html), clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg.git
```

go to src:

```
cd SparkR-pkg/pkg/src
```

assembly:

```
sbt assembly
```

and install:

```
R -e "devtools::install('.')"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184918/installing-of-sparkr this works very well.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I thought you may be looking for a new version after all.

Comment: then I'm trying to create a spark context by > sc <- sparkR.init(master="local[*]")
Error: could not find function "sparkR.init"

Comment: And how did you attach the library?

Comment: I just follow this link http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/5/exercises/sparkr.html
things works fine until I create the spark context

Comment: This exercises are no longer applicable in Spark 1.4+. Moreover it doesn't environment setup. SparkR is no standalone package. You can start with https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104946/discussion-between-lucia-and-zero323).