# false R version for package installation

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, version

I use R version `3.3.0 beta` on Ubuntu. This version is realized on 2016-03-30 according documentation:

```
user@user:~$ R --version
R version 3.3.0 beta (2016-03-30 r70404) -- "Supposedly Educational"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

Currently I want to install the package [PerfomanceAnalytics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html), which was realized in 2014 (see documentation). Anyway, I got next error message by installation:

```
> install.packages("PerfomanceAnalytics")
Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘PerfomanceAnalytics’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0 beta)
```

It seems that my R version is not correct... But this is the last stable version for Ubuntu. Or I'm false?

PS I have similar question about [RSpark installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184918/installing-of-sparkr). Probably I need also install from the directory. Can anybody tell me the right way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably not caused by the fact that you have an older version of R, I think you need to specify the source. The default source for downloading a package is from CRAN.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html

Comment: You can download the .tgz files and install them form you local path.

Answer (score 1):

You must install the R version which is required for the package too. I have the same problem with KDE package.