# How to update to SparkR 2.0.0 package in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to update from `SparkR 1.4.0` to `SparkR 2.0.0`, but I get the following error:

`had non-zero exit status`

This is because `SparkR 2.0.0` is not available on CRAN.

Similarly, from `SparkR 1.6.2` to `SparkR 2.0.0`, we get:

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘SparkR’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0)
```

How does one install `Spark 2.0.0` from there? (i dont want to install the SparkR because it's already installed as 1.6.2 nut i have to update it as 2.0.0)

Comment: i want to used read.jdbc function which is available in SparkR (2.0.0)

Comment: Read how to install R packages from source. Additionally it may fails if SparkR added some OS dependency you don't have, you need to read installation output to spot that.

Comment: @jangorecki  yup i already read it but its for SparkR(1.1.4).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing of SparkR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184918/installing-of-sparkr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SparkR requires not just an R package but an entire Spark backend to be pulled in. When you want to upgrade SparkR, you are upgrading Spark, not just the R package.

Nowadays you may want to refer to the `sparklyr` package as it makes all of this a whole lot easier.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "1.6.2")
spark_install(version = "2.0.0")
```

It also offers more functionality than SparkR.

Comment: Installation complete.
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) : Failed to set logging settings