# Does sparkR installations depend on R installation?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

For  the latest versions of SparkR (1.6 and 2.0) do I need R to be installed ? If I need R to run sparkR is it required to install R on all data nodes in a Yarn cluster with CDH and spark?

Comment: You can check [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/07/14/spark-1-4-for-rstudio/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184918/installing-of-sparkr)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need:

- R installation.
- all packages and native dependencies

installed on each worker node.